# SKAudioNode Difference init(fileNamed: String) between init(url: URL)

Tags: sprite-kit

i know a SKAudioNode use the AVFoundation to play the sound, but what is the Difference betwenn the two initializers

1. init(fileNamed: String)
2. init(url: URL)

Which one in the best to use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileNamed gets an asset file located in your main bundle

Url can get a file in any location you have access to.

Only advantage to fileNamed is there are no calls to directories or web services,  saving you a millisecond or 2